# How do I defeat Piranha Plants?

Tags: super-mario-run

There are "Defeat x Piranha Plants" objectives in Super Mario Run, so from that I assume that it must be possible to defeat a Piranha Plant. I just can't figure out how you would do it.

I've tried... jumping. That didn't work, so now I'm out of ideas tbh.

Is it even possible to defeat Piranha Plants in every case (like when they're hanging upside down)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least two ways to defeat the Piranha Plants.

1. As Adeese stated, if you can pick up an invincibility star you can just walk or jump straight through them.
2. Most levels with Piranha Plants also contain enemies with shells, i.e. Koopa Troopas or Buzzy Beetles. If you jump, stomp or spin strike onto these, this will send the shell off along the ground. The shell can then also kill the Piranha Plants. Of course, not every plant can be killed this way, but a lot of them are placed such that this is possible (particularly those that need to be killed to safely reach certain areas of a level).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to defeat Piranha Plants is when you are invincible after picking up a star. They are rare, though -- they only appear in some levels.